# Cannot access or find django many to many object after creating

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I have had to merge two functions in my Django app due to an API upgrade. Formerly had one function create all of the objects, and the second function access said objects via .get() and .filter() etc. Now, I've had to merge the two, and I've run into issues accessing those created objects.

```
View.py

                order = Order.objects.create(
                    user=user,
                    date_created=datetime.datetime.now(),
                )

                item = Item.objects.create(
                    price=price,
                    quantity=quantity,
                    order=order,
                )
                item.save()

                print(order.item_set.all()) #this is a blank array, where it used to be an array of items 
                print(Items.objects.filter(order=order)) #this is a blank queryset, where I would expect it to be full of created items



models.py
class Order(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField()
    paid_for = models.BooleanField(blank=False, null=False)
    submitted = models.BooleanField(blank=False, null=False)
    total_price = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)

class Item(models.Model):
    quantity = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    price = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Any idea what I can do to make the print statement have items in it once again?

I have tried to do `order.item_set.add(item)` but it did not work.

Comment: could you please share your model  and the whole view not just a part?

Comment: updated to include models

Comment: `print(Items.objects.filter(order=order))` will be blank because your model name is `Item` not `Items`.  Perhaps a typo?